# Outputting JSON to page

Tags: angular, rxjs

I'm having issues outputting JSON data to the page.
I can output the JSON Objects to the console using console.log, but not the page using angular.
I'm still new at this. Can anyone point on where I went wrong.

Error:

```
Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object]' of type 'object'. NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays.
```

post.service.ts

```
import {Http} from '@angular/http';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import {Injectable} from "@angular/core";
import {Post} from './post';

@Injectable()
export class PostService{

constructor(private _http:Http){


}
getPosts(){
return this._http.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts')
.map(res => res.json());

}
}
```

app.component.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import {PostService} from './post.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],
  providers: [PostService]
})
export class AppComponent {
private posts;

constructor(private _postService:PostService){
this.posts =_postService.getPosts();


}
}
```

app.component.html

```
<h1>
<ul>
<li *ngFor="let post of posts">
{{post.title}}
</li>

</ul>
</h1>
```

post.ts

```
export class Post{
id?: number;
body: string;
title: string;


}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to **subscribe** to your http request to get data and display it, you are currently trying to iterate through `Observable`, which is impossible. You should also use `OnInit` instead of `constructor`:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { PostService } from './post.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],
  providers: [PostService]
})

export class AppComponent {

private posts;

constructor(private _postService:PostService) {}

ngOnInit() {
    this._postService.getPosts().subscribe(
    (res) => {
     this.posts = res; <--
     });
}

}
```

Here's nice [article](https://scotch.io/tutorials/angular-2-http-requests-with-observables) about http requests with Observables, it has examples too.

Answer (score 0):

Function `getPost` from your class `PostService` returns an Observable, not the object. The traditional way to do this is to subscribe and assign the return value.

```
this._postService.getPosts().subscribe(result => this.posts = result);
```

Alternatively, you can [make use of the **async** pipe](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/common/index/AsyncPipe-pipe.html), which is preferred way of doing things.

```
this.posts$ = this._postService.getPosts();
```

And in your HTML template use the async pipe; for example:

```
<span>{{ posts$ | async | json }}</span>
```

By the way, this basic behavior has been discussed in [Tour of Heroes (ToH)](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/tutorial/), the official "getting started" tutorial for Angular which is highly based on a real-world application.